# Apply css rule on everything but not a selector and its children

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a scenario that a css rule should be applied to all selectors except one selector and whatever underneath it. 
For example I want to apply the css on everything inside `.parent` but not including `.child` and its children.

I tried the following, but didn't work...

```css
.parent *:not(.child *) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div>inside</div>
    <div>inside2</div>
  </div>
  <div>outside</div>
</div>
```

Comment: .parent > *:not(.child)

Comment: @VXp it works, but why should it be `.child *` and child `.child`?

Comment: @zb22 Can you rephrase the question? Are you asking about why the :not pseudo class didn't work with your complex selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should target any direct child of .parent that doesn't have the class of child as well as its descendants:**

```css
.parent> :not(.child),
.parent> :not(.child) * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div>inside</div>
    <div>inside2</div>
  </div>
  <div>outside</div>
  <div>
    <div>outside!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Why your selector didn't work**

```css
.parent *:not(.child *) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div>inside</div>
    <div>inside2</div>
  </div>
  <div>outside</div>
  <div>
    <div>outside!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Target any descendant of .parent that doesn't have the child class.
While yes you aren't assigning the background-color to .child, you're assigning it to both of its children...

**But I specified all descendants of .child within :not()**

> As with :is(), default namespace declarations do not affect the compound selector representing the subject of any selector within a :not() pseudo-class, unless that compound selector contains an explicit universal selector or type selector. (See :is() for examples.)
> https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#negation

I'm still trying to fully understand this part of the spec myself, but I think it just means that you can't do compound selectors within the :not() pseudo class

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't have the class of child" ?
`<div>inside2</div>` also doesn't have that class

Comment: @zb22 Very sorry but I don't understand your question

Answer (score 2):

You can target the child class with its own rule using "unset" or "initial" or another reasonable default value:

```
.parent {
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  background-color: unset;
}
```